# Using workers causing the browser to crash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, web-worker

I am trying to simulate around 10,000 objects using *three.js*. Since the objects are moving, I needed to calculate the trajectory at each instant. For that I decided to use workers. The following is my code (truncated for simplicity)

***main file***

```
var Position;

var worker = new Worker('scripts/worker.js');

$(function(){
    initSatData();
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        Position = e.data;
        plot(); // plots the objects
  }, false);
})
```

***worker.js***

```
importScripts('scriptUsed.js');
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

  var Position =[];
  var Data = e.data;

  for (var i = 0; i <= Data.length-1; i++) {
              // Does calculation
             Position .push(data_obtained);

    }


  self.postMessage({
    type: 'results',
    data: Position 
  })
})
```

Then in I called the function like this

```
function callWorker()
{
    worker.postMessage(Data); 

}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    callWorker();
}
```

It runs for some time and then crashes. With the following error

[image]

I believe that I am making a simple logical error, since I am using workers for the first time.